# SQL help, limiting number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

Given Table: **student**

```
| course  | Name| 
---------------
| science |   A |
| math    |   B |
| english |   A |
| physics |   A |
| chem    |   A |
| bio     |   B |
| geology |   B |
| history |   C |
```

I will order this table alphabetically.

Tmp table: **ordered_student**

```
| course  | Name| 
---------------
| bio     |   B |
| chem    |   A |
| english |   A |
| geology |   B |
| history |   C |
| math    |   B |
| physics |   A |
| science |   A |
```

By using the following code,

```
select Name, COUNT(*) as count from student group by Name
```

I was able to create temporary table

Tmp Table: **num_course_per_student**

```
| Name | count| 
---------------
|     A|    4 |
|     B|    3 |
|     C|    1 |
```

**GOAL** 
Let say, student is allowed to take only 2 courses. If a student is taking more than 2 courses, the student will take first 2 courses.

I should return the following..

```
| course  | Name| 
---------------
| bio     |   B |
| chem    |   A |
| english |   A |
| geology |   B |
| history |   C |
```

How should I do? Your help and suggestion would be much appreciated :) Thank you!

Comment: what's the criteria for ordering? alphabetically over `course`?

Comment: @neutrino ordering for the final table should be same as 'student' table. But, it can be alphabetically over course for simplification.

Comment: @neutrino I edited question as you instructed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
WITH s AS (
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY course) rank,
  * FROM student
)
SELECT course, name FROM s
WHERE RANK <= 2
ORDER BY course
```

Output:

```
course  name 
------- ---- 
bio     B    
chem    A    
english A    
geology B    
history C
```

See it working [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/151754).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
; with temp as (
    select 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Course) AS Rank,
        Name, 
        course 
    from student
)
SELECT Course, Name FROM temp WHERE Rank<=2
order by Course
```

Result:

```
Course  Name
bio     B
chem    A
english A
geology B
history C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  course,
  Name
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM student) t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 2 course FROM student WHERE Name = t1.Name ORDER BY course) t2
```